# iOS Removable Overlay Screen

Tags: ios

I have two pages in my app, in order to get to the second one you have to go through the first one. However when the second page is open I'd like to be able to swipe down on the second page, have it disappear at the bottom and still display the first page without having to reload it.

In order to accomplish this I assume both pages would have to be loaded at the same time, with the first page hidden behind the second page when it's up, kind of like an overlay screen, but I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with just presenting the second screen modally, and using the swipe as the trigger to dismiss it. When you return to the first page, the only things that will be reloaded would be anything that you've handled in viewWillAppear:, viewDidAppear: etc.

Comment: @0x7fffffff The only problem with that is that most of the content is loaded from my websites server, so a good majority of the loading is done in the viewDidAppear method. I'd like to be able to keep all the content preloaded so that I don't have to reload it, as it takes a second or two initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of presenting the 2nd view controller, use it as a child view controller.

If you are using storyboards:

1. Drag a container view onto your first view controller.
2. Then, a new view controller should appear with an 'embed' segue.
3. Delete that view controller and attach an embed segue from the container view to the 2nd view controller by ctrl-clicking and dragging like a normal segue.
4. Position that container view where ever you like (like at the bottom of the screen)
5. Then you can use animation to present it.
6. To dismiss it, perhaps use a pan gesture recogniser to drag it off the screen.
7. Add some physics (UIDynamicAnimator) for a more realistic effect.